# how to post data from form to postgres table through migration in sequelize orm

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, database-migration

have to post data from FORM html to POSTGRES table through migration sequelize orm
i have created table through migration....but not able to insert form data in to the table
form.html

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/register">
                            <fieldset class="p-4">
                                <input type="email" placeholder="Email*" id = "email" class="border p-3 w-100 my-2">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Password*" id = "password" class="border p-3 w-100 my-2">
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password*" id = "con_password" class="border p-3 w-100 my-2">
                                <div class="loggedin-forgot d-inline-flex my-3">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="registering" class="mt-1">
                                        <label for="registering" class="px-2">By registering, you accept our <a class="text-primary font-weight-bold" href="terms-condition.html">Terms & Conditions</a></label>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="d-block py-3 px-4 bg-primary text-white border-0 rounded font-weight-bold" onclick="registrationform()">Register Now</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

this below is my seeding file code :

seeds/20210823074536-Users.js

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    router.post('/register',async(req,res)=>{
    const { email,password: plainTextPassword } = req.body
    const password =  await bcrypt.hash(plainTextPassword,10);
    try{
      await queryInterface.bulkInsert('RegisterUsers', [{
       email: email,
       password: password ,
       con_password: password
     }])
    }
      catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    
    });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    
     await queryInterface.bulkDelete('RegisterUsers', null, {});
```

migration/
20210818092900-create-register-user.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('RegisterUsers', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      con_password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('RegisterUsers');
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't get what is "posting through migration"

Comment: you don't need to migrate anything to post data inside of the table, migrations are a for changing the schema of database, not to insert data into databse

Comment: ok@sairaj used  npx sequelize-cli seed:generate --name demo-user   to insert bulk into the table which is already created and the above code is seed file , now how to insert the data into the table

Comment: ya you have generated the seed now you have to run the seed to get the data into the table

Comment: check [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html), to see how to run seeds

Comment: ya i did that ,seeds generated ,migrated ..but the data is not in table

Comment: you see you have `router` logic inside of `up`  that's not the case in documentation you just have to run it no need of any router logic

Comment: If things are not working just delete the database and create it once again and start fresh by trying what I said in the answer below, it should work fine

Comment: ya tried that also now...migrated but table is still empty

Comment: anyway thankyou @sairaj

Comment: Hope I could solve your issue

Comment: still i dint get it @sairaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in models i have created a file
registerusers.js

```
const {Sequelize, Model,DataTypes}= require('sequelize')
const sequelize = new Sequelize("postgres","postgres","password",{
  "host":"localhost",
  "dialect":"postgres"
})
 
module.exports = {
  regusers: async (email,password) =>{
    console.log(email,password)
  class RegisterUsers extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  RegisterUsers.init({
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    //con_password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'RegisterUsers',
    schema:'shoppingcart'
  });
 // return RegisterUser;
 await RegisterUsers.create({
 email:`${email}`,
 password:`${password}`,
// con_password:`${con_password}`
 },
 {
schema:'shoppingcart'
 })
}
};
```

and this added to the router.js file

```
 router.post('/register',async(req,res)=>{
//console.log(req.body);
const { email,password: plainTextPassword } = req.body
const password =  await bcrypt.hash(plainTextPassword,10);
 try{
// // console.log(email)
// // console.log(password)
let reguser = {
    email: email,
    password: password
}


let data = await models.regusers(reguser.email,reguser.password);
console.log(data)
}catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
}
 })
```

and this bought the form data from frontend to the postgres database

Answer (score 0):

`npx sequelize-cli seed:generate --name demo-user` this command will create seed file in `seeders` folder, which looks something like

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Users', [{
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      email: 'example@example.com',
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date()
    }]);
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete('Users', null, {});
  }
};
```

seed script has nothing to do with routing, and then to run the script use the following command

`npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all`

after this command executes successfully you will have your data in databse